# Detect Shift key down using jna

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jna

I have implemented keyBoardHook, but however cannot detect the character pressed while shift key is down.

I have tried using the GetAsyncKeyState function of windows to detect when shift key is pressed. But this does not process shift+2 = @. it overrides the shift key and prints the keycode for 2.

i can obtain every key but however Shift + 2 are detected both as separate keys (Even though [SHIFT+2] gives @ on my keyboard). IE: The program outputs both SHIFT, and 2, but not what they produce: @.

Question:

How can i detect the characters produced when shift key is down.

Code i have written so far.

```
public class Keyhook {
private static volatile boolean quit;
private static HHOOK hhk;
private static LowLevelKeyboardProc keyboardHook;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final User32 lib = User32.INSTANCE;
    HMODULE hMod = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null);
    keyboardHook = new LowLevelKeyboardProc() {
        public LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT info) {
            if (nCode >= 0) {
                switch (wParam.intValue()) {
                    case User32.WM_KEYUP:

                    break;
                    case User32.WM_KEYDOWN: 
                    if(lib.GetAsyncKeyState(160) == 1){
                         System.out.println(info.vkCode);    
                      }
                    break;
                    case User32.WM_SYSKEYUP:

                        break;
                    case User32.WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
                        System.err.println("in callback, key=" + info.vkCode);
                        if (info.vkCode == 81) {
                            quit = true;
                        }
                }
            }
            return lib.CallNextHookEx(hhk, nCode, wParam, info.getPointer());
        }
    };
    hhk = lib.SetWindowsHookEx(User32.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboardHook, hMod, 0);
    System.out.println("Keyboard hook installed, type anywhere, 'q' to quit");
    //noinspection ConstantConditions
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (!quit) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.err.println("unhook and exit");
            lib.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }.start();

    // This bit never returns from GetMessage
    int result;
    MSG msg = new MSG();
    while ((result = lib.GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0)) != 0) {
        if (result == -1) {
            System.err.println("error in get message");
            break;
        } else {
            System.err.println("got message");
            lib.TranslateMessage(msg);
            lib.DispatchMessage(msg);
        }
    }
    lib.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk);
}
}
```

Comment: Have a look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/6237250/233906 and it's solution http://melloware.com/products/jintellitype/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to predict the generated output (some key combinations don't produce any output).  If Java generates a KeyTyped event, the generated string will be provided in the event, but I don't think there's any API (Java or native) that provides you with a keystroke to key string mapping.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [LowLevelKeyboardProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v%3Dvs.85)) documentation, the reason you cannot detect the shift key:

> Note  When this callback function is called in response to a change in
>   the state of a key, the callback function is called before the
>   asynchronous state of the key is updated. **Consequently, the
>   asynchronous state of the key cannot be determined by calling
>   GetAsyncKeyState from within the callback function.**